# How to enable compression for resources from IBM cdn?

Tags: ibm-cloud, gzip, cdn

We are using IBM CDN and which is mapped to our IIS server. If the resource is getting fetched directly from the server, gzip compression is enabled. But if the same resource is fetched through CDN it is not compressed.
How can I enable gzip compression for IBM CDN resources?

Answer (score 0):

First I think the IBM CDN you mentioned is the CDN service documented here [IBM CDN Service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/CDN/getting-started.html#getting-started)

By default, the IBM CDN service will use gzip to compress the response if the content type is one if text/html*, text/css*, application/x-javascript*.

If you found the IBM CDN doesn't compress the content as your origin, then can you share the detailed request and response header from the origin and the CDN?

Bali